# Get the domain of a second degree bivariate curve

Tags: conic-sections

I am writing a program which needs to sample one point from a second degree bivariate curve of the form:

$$
Ax^2 + Bx + Cy^2 + Dy + Exy + F = 0
$$

To get this sample point I only need to feed a value of $x$ to the formula, 
but I have to make sure it's in the domain of course. The problem is the coefficients are unknown and have to be evaluated at run time.

So, is there a formula for calculating the domain (or range)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you choose an $x$, what's left is a quadratic equation in $y$. The *discriminant* of that equation is
$$ \tag{1} \Delta_x =(D+Ex)^2-4C(Ax^2+Bx+F)$$
which rearranges to a quadratic polynomial in $x$:
$$ \tag{2} \Delta_x = (E^2-4AC)x^2 + (2DE-4BC)x + (D^2-4CF) $$
You can use the quadratic formula on $(2)$ to find the out which ranges of $x$ make $\Delta_x$ nonnegative.

Comment: Is it possible for such a curve not to existe in $R^2$? Or will it always existe for any combination of $A,B,C,D,E,F$?

Comment: @qed: The solution set can be empty -- say, for $A=F=1$ and $B=C=D=E=0$ the equation reduces to $x^2+1=0$.